# A question about topology regarding its conditions

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

A question from a rookie.

As we know, $(X, T)$ is a topological space, on the following conditions,

1. The union of a family of $T$-sets, belongs to $T$;
2. The intersection of a *FINITE* family of $T$-sets, belongs to $T$;
3. The empty set and the whole $X$ belongs to $T$.

So when the condition 2 is changed into:

2'. The intersection of a family of $T$-sets, belongs to $T$;

can anyone give a legitimate topological space as a counterexample to condition 2'?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say just 'the intersection' or 'the union', I assume you're referring to a countable number.  A $\sigma$-algebra, for example, satisfies 1, 2', and 3. Thus $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$, where $\mathcal B$ are the Borel sets, is a viable topology on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of intervals $(-1/n,\ 1/n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ is only $\{0\}$ which is not open in $\mathbb R$ with the euclidean topology.

Comment: Thanks man. I have really been hanging there for a while.

Comment: It is THAT counter-example every one should know after a while :-) For a less trivial one, take an infinite set with the cofinite topology.

Answer (score 2):

Stefan H. has provided perhaps the canonical counterexample.  But just for some further information, a topological space in which the intersection of arbitrary families of open sets are open is called an [*Alexandrov space*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology).  A basic fact is that a topological space $X$ is an Alexandrov space iff every $x \in X$ has a smallest open neighbourhood.

> In the ($\Rightarrow$) direction, if $X$ is an Alexandroff space, then for each $x \in X$  the intersection of all open neighbourhoods of $x$ will itself be an open neighbourhood of $x$, and will be a subset of all open neighbourhoods of that point.  In the  ($\Leftarrow$) direction, if by $U_x$ we denote the smallest open neighbourhood of $x \in X$, then given any family $\mathcal{U}$ of open sets, if $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{U}$, then $U_x \subseteq U$ for all $U \in \mathcal{U}$, and so in fact $U_x \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal{U}$: it follows that $\bigcap \mathcal{U} = \bigcup \{ U_x : x \in \bigcap \mathcal{U} \}$, and is an open set.

Thus if any point in a topological space does not have a smallest open neighbourhood, the space is not Alexandrov.

In the presence of even a weak separation axiom like [T$_1$-ness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space), Alexandrov spaces are quite simple: they are all discrete!  Therefore any non-discrete T$_1$-space is not Alexandrov.

Comment: Thanks. It is getting deep, but I will try my best to catch up. You guys are wonderful. Love being here.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where to find the full reference of Latex language, since what I have is rather limited?

Comment: For the pleasure of my first LaTeX writing, I give my proof for the ($⇐$) direction as follows. Given any family $\{U\}$ of open sets, $U_0=⋂U$ is either empty set (so already an open set), or a nonempty set. In the latter case, for any $x∈U_0$, $x$'s smallest open set $U_x⊆U_0$. Otherwise $U_x⋂U_0$ will be an even smaller open set containing $x$, which contradicts with $U_x$ being samllest. Finally, it follows that $U_0=⋃\{U_x:x∈U_0\}$ is an open set.

Comment: @Lan: You're welcome! It's always nice to introduce others to weird and wonderful math concepts!

Comment: @Lan: In your ($\Leftarrow$) when you state "... otherwise $U_x \cap U_0$ will be an even smaller open set containing $x$..." you seem to already assume that $U_0$ is open (which is what we are trying to prove).  For $\LaTeX$ help as it works on this site, see [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348).  $\LaTeX$ is rendered here via MathJax [which supports many — but not all — commands](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html).

Comment: You are right. My proof is defective. From your proof, I get the idea that, the intersection of infinite family of open sets, are transformed to the union of any family of $U_x$.